# How i can make multiline label in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, label, kivymd

I want make multiline label in KV string:

```
MDLabel:
    text: '

              MultilineText'
```

But i receive this error:

```
 text: '
       8:                     
 >>    9:                     MultilineText'
      10:                     
      11:            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
```

...
Invalid indentation, must be a multiple of 4 spaces
Use triple bracket i can't, because my code already in triple bracket:

```
'''
<Code>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 60
    FloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: '
                     
                     MultilineText'
                     
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
'''
```

I want multiline long text in one label. help(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky topic. Try this:

```
'''
<Code>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 60
    FloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: '\\n' +\
                  '\\n' +\
                  'MultilineText'
                     
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
'''
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried it ou and it Works nicely !!
MDLabel:
markup : True
multiline : True
font_size :'12sp'
text: '[b][color=#007acc] Derived Cust Bullet Rates (%) [/color][/b]'+'\n' +' Rate convention linked'
pos_hint: {'center_x': 1,'center_y': 0.75}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).